# Add a new item to a Dynamodb using a AWS lambda function each time a function is executed with Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to modify a Dynamodb table each time a Lambda function is executed.
Specifically, I create a simple lambda function that returns a list of S3 bucket names and this function run each minute thanks to a Cloudwatch's rule.
However, as I said before, my goal is to also update a Dynamodb each time the same function is executed. Specifically I want to add each time a new Item with the same attribute (so let's say the function is executed 1000 times, I want 1K items/rows).

However I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions? Here's the code:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket_list = []
    for b in s3.buckets.all():
        print(b.name)
        bucket_list.append(b.name)
        
    response = "done"
    table.put_item(
        Item = {
            "Update": response
        }
        )
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": bucket_list
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors

Comment: No errors, the code works but the final table in Dynamodb remains with one row only. Instead what I want is that every time the file is executed a row is added to the db...maybe istead of using "Item" I should use a cloudwatch log id of the event...but I don't know how to get it

Comment: maybe instead of using "Item" = { "Update": "done"}, it will be better to have specific log id = {"Update": specific log timestamp} but again..I don't know how to do it

Comment: I don't know what is the structure of your db, but you seem not to be setting up any primary key for your table.

Comment: Forget to mention. I have added  It manually to the Dynamodb. Is "Update"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `PutItem` does overwrite exiting items, if they are the same. So every time you try to insert `Update=done`, it just overwrites the same item.

The very first sentence of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) states:

> Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item.

So what you need to do is to put something in your item that is unique, so that a new item is created instead of the old one being overwritten.

You could create a UUID or something like that, but I think it would be beneficial to use the time of execution. This way you could see when your last execution was etc.

```py
from datetime import datetime

[...]

table.put_item(
    Item = {
        "Update": response,
        "ProcessingTime": datetime.now().isoformat()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Jens stated, which is 100% correct.

You could use data from the `event`. The `event` will look something like this:

```json
{
  "id": "cdc73f9d-aea9-11e3-9d5a-835b769c0d9c",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:123456789012:rule/ExampleRule"
  ],
  "detail": {}
}
```

The `id` value will be 100% unique, and the `time` value will be the time it was triggered.

Comment: Uh. That's a great idea to either use the `id` or `time`. Did not think about that.